# Access file from another server using asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET application I have to show some images. Actually these images saved in some **other server**. In my database I have the file path. I need to access file from remote server to my application. How can I do that? I am using the following code

```
imgFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strFullPath, 
                              strPkStock + "_*", 
                              SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

But this throws an error saying **"Access to the path denied"**

Comment: Your IIS worker process needs to have access to that path ?  Have you checked that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to have file system access on other server to do this and I am sure you will not have it.

The shortest way to get it done is, publish the images folder from other server and use the url of the images to access it rather then file system path. This way, your asp.net application will be able to easily access these images. In fact, it will be the client browser which will directly access these images from the other server, you will just change the src of images.

Comment: +1 making images accesible over HTTP is probably easiest solution (also one may need to think about security implications...)

Answer (score 2):

Murtuza Kabul's suggestion to access files over HTTP/HTTPS is probably easiest approach. You may use HTTPS with client ceritficates to prevent other users/machines to read files from the same HTTPS server.

If you want to access files directly on other server's shared folder you need to make sure that code that accesses files runs under account that have at least read permissions for that shared folder.

Note that default configuration (where code runs under either special anonymous account or calling user's credentials) account that code runs under will not have permissions on other servers (anonymous becuse it is local account, user's due to restrictions on delegation also called "NTLM one hop hell").

Your easiest bet is to run app polls under some account that have permissions on other server and de-impersonate current user to process account. You can also explcitly impresonate some account to access remote files.